# MySQL Entry to Database Not Working

Tags: php, mysql

I'm going through a course on MySQL, and I'm learning how to make a user entry bit of code (email and password) where the info in the script will be put into the database on phpMyAdmin. I can't seem to get it to work? My code doesn't have any errors when I put it through an error checker. I'm also completely new to PHP and MySQL. I know it can find the database, because I can update existing data.

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect("host", "username", "password", "username");

if (mysqli_connect_error()) {

    die ("There was an error connecting to the database");

} 

$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES('email', 'password')"; 

mysqli_query($link, $query);

$query = "SELECT * FROM users";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

 $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

 echo "Your email is ".$row[1]." and your password is ".$row[2];

}

?>
```

Comment: Zero based array, start with $row[0] and $row[1]

Comment: @RicardoOrtegaMagaña True, yet the `[1]` should at least show something and this isn't really what the question's about. They state the insert doesn't work. As per title *"Entry to Database Not Working"*.

Comment: I don't see any error checking here. You state you put that through an error checker, being what exactly? I feel you're not telling us the real/full story. Your value contain what seem to be that you're trying to enter something other than string literals.

Comment: Fred -ii-, I'm using this website to check for errors - http://phpcodechecker.com/

Comment: that place doesn't know what your db contains. it's a "php" checker, not a db checker. and we don't know how you're using this, on your pc? hosted? as `http://localhost` or `file:///`?

Comment: RicardoOrtegaMagana, I'm outputting one from my database that I entered myself. And that will show up in the browser. But the entry I'm trying to make through MySQL is not showing up in my phpMyAdmin database.

Comment: I can't keep guessing. Someone posted a (wrong) answer below; ask them. I posted a comment about how you're using this and another about checking for errors, to which I now see another answer which just basically "wrote" what I asked you to do. ask them.

Comment: Fred -ii-, I'm using a msql.username.hostname link in the mysqli_connect() section as the host. I have a hosted server for it.

Comment: I'll have to pass on this one, sorry. Again; see the answers below. I can't submit an answer for this; too many unknowns.

Comment: PRINT OUT THE ERRORS AND POST THEM! IT WILL TELL YOU EXACTLY WHATS GOING WRONG :D :D

Answer (score 0):

Created a refined version. Check it.

```
   <?php

    $link = mysqli_connect("host", "username", "password", "username");

    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {

        die ("There was an error connecting to the database");

    } 

    $query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES('email', 'password')"; 

    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    if($result != false)
    {
        echo "The record has been successfully inserted.<br>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error Occured in the INSERT query.<br>Error : ".mysqli_error($link);
    }

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    if($result != false)
    {
        echo mysqli_num_rows($result)." Records found.<br>";
        while($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo $rows["email"]."<br>";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Error Occured in the SELECT query.<br>Error : ".mysqli_error($link);
    }


    mysqli_close($link);

    ?>
```

Comment: Nandan, It's giving me this warning message - Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in server url on line 20
Error Occured in the INSERT query.
Error : 1 Records found.

Comment: Replace `$conn` with `$link`

Comment: @Colton, Yes PaulSpiegel is right, replace $conn by $link. I often use $conn as connection object. Anyway I have updated the answer, check it.

Comment: You shouldn't just dump a bunch of code. Explain what was wrong with the original code, and what you changed to fix it.

Comment: It returned back that there was an error in the insert query. Like you have it set to do. As well as a duplicate entry error.                                                  Error Occured in the INSERT query.
Error : Duplicate entry '0' for key 'PRIMARY'1 Records found. How do I determine the error? I'm knew to MySQL.

Comment: @Barmar, Colton will surely run this code. The code doesn't have anything to explain. Putting the else condition will help in error solving. Moreover that code should work without any errors and else part will show the query errors which can be traced easily.

Comment: @Colton The error is clearly saying that the data you are trying to insert already exists in the table.Tell me How many fields you have in the table ? Which is the primary key ? Quick check: delete all entries in the table and try to run the query, you must be able insert for the first time.

Comment: Answers aren't just for the benefit of the OP. SO is supposed to be a repository of useful questions and answer that provide education to all the users. We shouldn't force all readers to do a comparison between the original code and the answer, and figure out the reason for the changes.

Comment: @Barmar OP is the first priority. Answer should be helpful for OP. Anyway, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

*It turns out I didn't set the auto_increment setting, therefore making the way I set up my database incorrect! He set up another database in the tutorials I was going through, and I found out that as he did it. Thank you everyone for the effort to help me solve my problem!*

Answer (score -3):

Why you don't try receiving them with php?

And simply make

```
$email= $POST['email']
$password= $POST['password']
```

And change the query to

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES(" .$email. ", ". $password.")";
```

Comment: I have to be honest; if I could downvote this, I would. It's full of errors.